# Which is the better code: to initialize a variable, or simply declare it?

Tags: java

If I am declaring instance variables to be used and manipulated within methods later in the class, is it better to simply declare them, or assign them a value (such as zero).

Which of the following is better coding?

```
private int price;
private int stock;
```

or

```
private int price = 0;
private int stock = 0;
```

If both variable are to be used in various methods in the class.
I am asking this as I received an error "variable stock may not have been initialized" when compiling the program.

Comment: depends on how you use them

Comment: Which do you feel is simpler/clearer?

Comment: I like to declare them if I do not need an initial value (initializing seems unnecessary sometimes), but this error is bothering me. It might be due to not making the variable accessible by methods within the class but I'm not sure as I've just started with Java.

Comment: It depends if you want them initialised on start or whether you will initialise them using later. I advocate using either the class constructor or an initialiser to initialise them if the values are dependant on other variables. Primitive variables that aren't initialised in that way use the default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will not be different in term of value. As int is set as 0 by default. However, setting it explicitly will tend to overkill the initialization.

Refers to this link : http://www.odi.ch/prog/design/newbies.php under Overkill initialization section.

It is not encourage to set to default value (e.g. 0 for int, false for boolean ) explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

in that case, there is no difference.
int is a primitive so it's default is 0

Comment: So it's value is automatically set to 0 when I declare it?

Comment: @user3718563 in case of fields, yes, they have default values (boolean -> `false`, primitive numeric types -> `0`, references -> `null`). BUT if we are talking about local variables (not fields) then they need to be explicitly initialized or you will not be able to use them.